# Perfectly centered (responsive?) div

Tags: html, css

I want to make a perfectly centered/responsive div.

How would I go about that? Typically to move things I float them or use position: absolute;, but I would like to do so in relation to the browser window as opposed to just generally moving things around.

Comment: vertically or horizontally?

Answer (score 1):

This will center the div horizontally:

```
#yourDiv {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `margin: auto;` along with absolute positioning for responsive vertical/horizontal centering:

```
<section></section>

section {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
    background: #f4d4c4;
    height: 100px; /* The only caveat is there needs to be a height defined */
    margin: auto;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/uLDVM/

Comment: Related: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/09/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/

Answer (score 0):

Here s [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jtmLP/) that centers it both horizontally and vertically

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px; 
    border: 3px solid red;
    margin: 50% auto;
}
```

Comment: @Adrift what is not responsive?

Comment: @Adrift you mean vertically?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use.

```
.centered {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best method using CSS would be to use `margin` and a `max-width` to control its width. Like this:

```
div {
  max-width: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Now to change its value on the browser resize, either use `media query` or you can use `%`.

#### Media Query

```
@media only screen (max-width: 800px) {
  // change the properties if the screen is no 
  // larger than 800px in width
}
```

#### Percentage

```
div {
  max-width: 5%;
  margin: 0 auto; // will only align it horizontally
}
```

You can use `position: absolute` and then use `0` for each four sides of it. To keep it centered and strecthed to the borders, while it won't strecth because of max-width.

This way, you will have the div centered and responding to the browser.